# count words containing atleast one alphanumeric character in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want tocount words containing atleast one alphanumeric character in a string.
Ex:- str = `who is mukesh's father ?`
Result should be 4. `?` should not be counted as a word. words containg only symbols sshould not be counted.
How can I do that ?

I tried something like this `str.match(/[\w]+/gi).length`

But it counts `hello'man'how'are/you` as 5 words.

Comment: You can [test your regex here](https://regex101.com/r/iI0cQ4/1). Looks like you want to add `'`... to your character class: [`[\w'-]+`](https://regex101.com/r/iI0cQ4/2) (also added hyphen). Or [`[^\W_][-\w']*`](https://regex101.com/r/iI0cQ4/3) to require at least one alnum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
var str = "who is mukesh's father ?"

var allItems = str.split(/\s/g).filter(function(item){
   return item.match(/\w/);
});

console.log( "output is " + allItems.length )
```

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek it is still treated as one word only

Comment: @Tushar thanks, but `item.match(/\w/)` will return true if `item` has even one alphanumeric character. Right?

Comment: it works for me. Can you please explain a little bit ?

Comment: @tarun14110 I am simply splitting by space `\s` and then filtering the resulting array to check if every item has a alphanumeric character `\w` in it.